# Zend framework's tool for test performance

Tags: php, performance, optimization, zend-framework2

it's a simple question that i'm looking for a tool which can help me to show up  the performance of an application zend framework version 2.

**update**

```
Additional information:
Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\SessionManager.php:111
Message:
Session validation failed
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\Session\SessionManager->start()
#1 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\AdminController.php(731): Zend\Session\AbstractContainer->__construct('mySession')
#2 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Application\Controller\AdminController->tableauDeBordAction()
#3 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\public\index.php(13): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ZendDeveloperTools`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) to test performance and debugging your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i've configure it out but how to show up the result?how to make it work ?

Comment: Okay you need to load `ZendDeveloperTools` module in `application.config` file. You'll see a zf2 bar in the bottom of page. For more info please follow this link http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/zend-developer-tools-zf2-debug-toolbar-install/

Comment: i have a problem , i can see the bar in the bottom now i have an other problem : i can't log in after installing the zendDevelopperTools...

Comment: It depends on your application's authentication functionality. Are you using some module?

Comment: the application is built on doctrine 2 and i have jus tone module which application.

Comment: Is there any error you can see or just a blank page? Plus check your error log to see errors. If you are on linux, run this command in terminal `tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log` and then try to login errors and warnings will appear in the terminal. If you are on windows, open up `your_path_to_xampp/apache/logs/error.log` in any editor. Select all contents delete them and save file. Then try to login any errors and warnings will appear. Ideally you must enable `error_reporting` in your application.

Comment: i've add the error in the question , plz see the update ( i can't understand the error :/ ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61501/discussion-between-bilal-and-may-saghira).

Comment: problem resolved just edit the zenddevelopertools.local.php like mentionned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519800/zenddevelopertools-module-not-displaying-a-toolbar-in-zf2-beta5 thanks for you time :)

Comment: can u tell where can i find a tuto how to integrate BjyProfiler with doctrine2 ?

Comment: http://samminds.com/2013/03/zfcuser-bjyauthorize-and-doctrine-working-together/