# Can't log in after adding ZendDevelopperTools to Zend framwork 2 project?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i have a problem , i have an application working with zend franmework 2 and doctrine.when i added zendDevelopperTools i can't log in , the application stoped working.
i've add this to index.php :

```
define('REQUEST_MICROTIME', microtime(true));
```

and i've copy the ZendDevelopperTools to vendor Directory , then edit the application.config.php like this :

```
'modules' => array(
        'DoctrineModule',
                'DoctrineORMModule',
                'Application', 
                'ZendDeveloperTools',
    ),
   'module_listener_options' => array(

        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
```

then copy `ZendDeveloperTools/config/zenddevelopertools.local.php.dist` to
`./config/autoload/zenddevelopertools.local.php`.

**Error :**

```
Additional information:
Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\SessionManager.php:111
Message:
Session validation failed
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\Session\SessionManager->start()
#1 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\AdminController.php(731): Zend\Session\AbstractContainer->__construct('mySession')
#2 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Application\Controller\AdminController->tableauDeBordAction()
#3 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\wamp\www\mycoreg\public\index.php(13): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

do i miss something ? any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: By `vendor` directory, you mean `vendor\zendframework\DEVELOPER_FOLDER` right? Also what is the error exactly? You have only mentioned 'the application stopped working'

Comment: thanks for the reply , i've add the error see the updated answer, for the folder no it's directly inside vendor not inside vendor/zendframework.

Comment: Have you tried by commenting the `//define('REQUEST_MICROTIME', microtime(true));` statement?

Comment: yeah i've tried but that doesn't fix the problem :/

Comment: I assume you have tried commenting the `'ZendDeveloperTools',` from the `application.config.php -> modules` too. You must be using some `Session Container` in the `AdminController`, I guess.

Comment: problem resolved just edit the zenddevelopertools.local.php like mentionned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519800/zenddevelopertools-module-not-displaying-a-toolbar-in-zf2-beta5